# Dell XPS 9560 support

Tags: nvidia, dell, xps

I have been a user of ubuntu since 2008. I have used in every workstation, notebook that I have. I am not a OS guy I work mainly in development of embedded systems. I purchased Dell XPS 9560 recently and tried installing ubuntu in it however it started to crash even after installing proprietary nvidia drivers. This is forcing me to move towards windows which I don't want to do. Is there any plan fixes in the pipeline to solve this and if so when would they be released.

Best Regards

Comment: I'd have a read of [this](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux#).

Answer (score 0):

If your Dell XPS 9560 is behaving like a curmudgeon, have you tried letting Ubuntu select the nvidia driver automatically? Uninstall the existing nvidia driver, reboot, and run this command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
```

The `install` command of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.